# Bootstrap badge function error on the tooltip using escape symbol in the datatable js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, jquery-ui-tooltip

I use the following code

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        var te='something';    
    var heart='"<div><span class=\"badge badge-pill badge-success\"><i class=\"far fa-heart\"></i></span></div>"';
    var td1='<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" data-html="true"  title='+heart+'><div class="far fa-thumbs-up>'+te+'</div></button>';
    $('td:eq(1)',row).html(td1);


    var td2='<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" data-html="true"  title="12345"><div class="far fa-thumbs-up">'+te+'</div></button>';
    $('td:eq(2)',row).html(td2);
    }
});
```

I use the EscapeFormat symbol or not use ,all got the same tooltip code break in `<div><sapn class= >`

https://jsfiddle.net/housekeepings/v8x9wn03/26/

How can I fix the error~Call someone help me!thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be extra careful when you build "DOM strings" like this. To correct the error :

- Remove quote redundancy (`""` inside `''` which contain more `""`)
- Use `&quot;` instead of `\"` where needed, i.e `class=&quot;far fa-heart&quot;`
- Close quote correctly after `fa-thumbs-up`
- Quote title, i.e `title="'+heart+'"`

→

```
var heart='<div><span class=&quot;badge badge-pill badge-success&quot;><i class=&quot;far fa-heart&quot;></i></span></div>';
var td1='<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="'+heart+'"><div class="far fa-thumbs-up">'+te+'</div></button>';
```

You will also need a handler that triggers `tooltip()` when the table is redrawn:

```
$('#example').on('init.dt draw', function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Fixed version of the fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/kcy8dzjh/**

Comment: Thank you for your great help! I try and work very well! Can I ask about the responsive function When the screen size changed and the responsive  works, can the  createdRow tooltip still work well? How to write the $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() again when  the responsive  happened?

Comment: @robspin Thank you for accepting the answer. You could initialize tooltips on the [**responsive-display**](https://datatables.net/reference/event/responsive-display) event as well. I guess that would work. If you want to work on the row node in the handler you can use `row.nodes().to$()` ...